# How do I implement a delay in onClick?

Tags: android

I have an onclick on a table row, I want to change the color of the row for a second before the next screen is displayed. Is this possible? Here is my current code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String sdet_id;
int det_id;
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
det_id = v.getId();
sdet_id = String.valueOf(det_id);
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("demo.learningdroid.com", "demo.learningdroid.com.details");
i.putExtra("Det_id", sdet_id);
startActivity(i);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```

Comment: you can use 

    `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() 
    { /*do Intent stuff here*/ }
    , 1000);`

... but for FSM sake user should wait for what he wants to get? ... it will be annoying ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `postDelayed()`

```
    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your code that opens another activity
        }
    }, 1000L);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {

                      Intent i=new Intent(SearxhJobs.this,JobsTypes.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                  }
              }, 5000);
```

Here it waits upto 5 seconds to launch activity.

Hope it helps